# 1984 - What does O'Brien mean by this sentence?

Tags: character-analysis, george-orwell, nineteen-eighty-four

While Winston is being held prisoner, O'Brien walks in the room for the first time and the conversation goes something like this:

> **Winston:** They got you too!
>
> **O'Brien:** Yes, they got me a long time ago.

Does this mean that O'Brien, like Winston, was once a rebel, but was caught and converted? If so, how come O'Brien hasn't been shot already? We learn in the book that even if people are reformed, they still get killed.